# Aligning batched sliding frame timeseries data for tensorflow/keras using timeseries_dataset_from_array and TimeseriesGenerator respectively

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, training-data

I have multiple input features and a singular target feature that correspond 1:1 to each other's index; meaning there should be no forward-looking or backward-looking when it comes to comparing inputs to targets: `input[t] <=> target[t]`. Essentially, I have already time-shifted my targets backwards to their corresponding input indexes for training purposes.

Under normal operating procedures, I would use `N` periods worth of past data in order to predict 1 future value, `N` periods ahead. As the frame shifts forward in time, each respective slot is filled with the `[t+N]` forecast, recorded at `[t]`.

Now, based on whatever environment I'm developing in, I will need to use either `timeseries_dataset_from_array` or `TimeseriesGenerator` to batch my data (based on system support). I need to know if the implementation I made produces batches that will do what I expect when running `model.fit()` in keras. I'm unsure of whether or not keras is internally shifting data during fitting that I'm unaware of that might lead to poor results.

I'm using an LSTM potentially with the `stateful` argument so I need to ensure my batches are a perfect fit, and I also wanted to ensure the batch sizes are a factor of 2 (according to some posts regarding processor efficiency). I've tried implementing my own function for making this happen given a few additional assumptions regarding validation/test sizes. On the surface it appears that everything looks good, but since I'm unsure of keras' internals I don't know if I've made a blunder.

My *question* is whether or not I've properly aligned/batched the inputs and targets using `timeseries_dataset_from_array`/`TimeseriesGenerator` such that running `model.fit()` will train using losses/metrics that compare the target at time `[t]` with the predicted value at time `[t]` using inputs at time `[t]`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

use_ts_data = True
try:
    # Comment this line out if you want to test timeseries_dataset_from_array
    raise ImportError("No TDFA for you")
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import timeseries_dataset_from_array as ts_data
except (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError):
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator as ts_gen

    use_ts_data = False

def gp2(size):
    return np.power(2, int(np.log2((size))))

def train_validate_test_split(
    features, targets, train_size_ratio=0.5, max_batch_size=None, memory=1,
):
    def batch_size_with_buffer(buffer, available, desired, max_batch_size):
        batch_size = gp2(min(desired, max_batch_size or np.inf))
        if available < batch_size * 3 + buffer:
            # If we don't have enough records to support this batch_size, use 1 power lower
            batch_size = np.power(2, np.log(batch_size) / np.log(2) - 1)
        return int(batch_size)

    memory = max(1, memory)
    surplus = memory - 1
    test_size_ratio = 1 - train_size_ratio
    total_size = features.shape[0]
    smallest_size = int(total_size * test_size_ratio / 2)

    # Error on insufficient data
    def insufficient_data():
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"Insufficient data on which to split train/validation/test when ratio={train_size_ratio}%, nobs={total_size} and memory={memory}"
        )

    if total_size < memory + 3:
        insufficient_data()

    # Find greatest batch size that is a power of 2, that fits the smallest dataset size, and is no greater than max_batch_size
    batch_size = batch_size_with_buffer(
        surplus, total_size, smallest_size, max_batch_size
    )
    test_size = smallest_size - smallest_size % batch_size

    # Create/align the datasets
    if use_ts_data:
        index_offset = None
        
        start = -test_size
        X_test = features.iloc[start - surplus:]
        y_test = targets.iloc[start:]

        end = start
        start = end - test_size
        X_validation = features.iloc[start - surplus:end]
        y_validation = targets.iloc[start:end]

        end = start
        start = (total_size + end - surplus) % batch_size
        X_train = features.iloc[start:end]
        y_train = targets.iloc[start + surplus:end]
    else:
        index_offset = memory
        _features = features.shift(-1)
        
        start = -test_size - memory
        X_test = _features.iloc[start:]
        y_test = targets.iloc[start:]

        end = start + memory
        start = end - test_size - memory
        X_validation = _features.iloc[start:end]
        y_validation = targets.iloc[start:end]

        end = start + memory
        start = (total_size + end - memory) % batch_size
        X_train = _features.iloc[start:end]
        y_train = targets.iloc[start:end]

    # Record indexes
    test_index = y_test.index[index_offset:]
    validation_index = y_validation.index[index_offset:]
    train_index = y_train.index[index_offset:]
    
    if memory > X_train.shape[0] or memory > X_validation.shape[0]:
        insufficient_data()

    format_data = ts_data if use_ts_data else ts_gen
    train = format_data(X_train.values, y_train.values, memory, batch_size=batch_size)
    validation = format_data(
        X_validation.values, y_validation.values, memory, batch_size=batch_size
    )
    test = format_data(X_test.values, y_test.values, memory, batch_size=batch_size)

    # Print out the batched data for inspection
    def results(dataset, index):
        print("\n-------------------\n")
        print(f"Index:\n\n", index, "\n\n")
        last_i = len(dataset) - 1
        for i, batch in enumerate(dataset):
            inputs, targets = batch
            if i == 0:
                print(
                    f"First:\n\nInputs:\n",
                    inputs[0][-1],
                    "...",
                    inputs[-1][-1],
                    f"\n\nTargets:\n",
                    targets[0],
                    "...",
                    targets[-1],
                )
                print(inputs.shape, targets.shape, "\n\n")
            if i == last_i:
                print(
                    f"Last:\n\nInputs:\n",
                    inputs[0][-1],
                    "...",
                    inputs[-1][-1],
                    f"\n\nTargets:\n",
                    targets[0],
                    "...",
                    targets[-1],
                )
                print(inputs.shape, targets.shape, "\n\n")
        print("\n-------------------\n")

    results(train, train_index)
    results(validation, validation_index)
    results(test, test_index)

    return (
        batch_size,
        train,
        validation,
        test,
        train_index,
        validation_index,
        test_index,
    )

# inputs and targets are expected to be aligned (i.e., loss functions should subtract the predicted target@t from the actual target@t)
x = np.arange(101)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=x)
df['inputs'] = x
df['targets'] = x

batch_size, train, validation, test, train_index, validation_index, test_index = train_validate_test_split(df['inputs'], df['targets'], train_size_ratio=0.5, max_batch_size=2, memory=8)
```

Comment: What *exactly* is your *question*?

Comment: @desertnaut I'm looking for confirmation of whether or not I've prepared (aligned) my inputs/targets properly such that Keras/Tensorflow is running losses/metrics on the right timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All loss/metric functions rely on `y_pred` and `y_true` assume matching indices. There's nothing special that Keras does in the background.